# Mule async request-reply

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I actually invoke an `exe` with the `expression-component` through a http-request on port 8081. The `exe` sends a http-request on port 8082 and I'm able to log the output.
Finally i have to send the output of the reply-flow back to the main-flow but i dont know how...

Here is my code:

```
<flow name="mainFlow" doc:name="mainFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <request-reply timeout="10000">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="request" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="reply" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
    </request-reply>
</flow>

<flow name="request" doc:name="request">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="request" doc:name="VM" />
    <expression-component doc:name="Expression">Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\myfile.exe arg1");</expression-component>
</flow>

<flow name="reply" doc:name="reply">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8082" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="one-way" />
    <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['test']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="reply" doc:name="VM" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you are carrying the `MULE_CORRELATION_ID` message property through the `exe` down to `http://localhost:8082` otherwise the `request-reply` message processor has no way to correlate the asynchronous reply with the current request.

For example, pass the correlation ID has a second argument to the `exe`:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\myfile.exe arg1 " + message.correlationId);
</expression-component>
```

And make sure the `exe` propagates the correlation ID towards `http://localhost:8082` in an HTTP header named `X-MULE_CORRELATION_ID`.

Comment: I think you also have to remove the MULE_REPLYTO property from the request outbound: <vm:outbound-endpoint path="request">
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>  
         </vm:outbound-endpoint>

Comment: Good point. Yes, possibly, depending on how/if the expression component affects the reply to mechanism.

Comment: I am wondering if you need `<vm:outbound-endpoint path="reply" doc:name="VM" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>` you could have just set the MULE_REPLYTO and to the inbound queue name and it should work... I am learning here too and at some level trying to clarify my understanding